# getting a list of values from a query set object in Django

Tags: django

I have the following object result from query set on a model as follow :

```
ddd = Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=dd).values_list('sub_category_name', flat=True)
```

the query set I obtained:

```
<QuerySet ['car', 'spare parts', 'truck', 'motor cycle']>
```

then tried:

```
print(ddd.values('sub_category_name'))
```

I obtained the following result:

```
<QuerySet [<Post_Sub_Category: car>, <Post_Sub_Category: spare parts>, <Post_Sub_Category: truck>, <Post_Sub_Category: motor cycle>]
```

How to access the values only and make list of them as string :['car','spare parts','truck','motor cycle'].

the first query set seems that it gave me what I want. However, When I use following if  statement. it does not executed:

```
if 'car' in ddd:
 #  do some thing
```

as you can see 'car' should be in the list. so, I could not understand why the if statement has not been executed.

any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use values_list and convert the resulting queryset to list. In case car, spare parts, truck, motor cycle are the name field of your model do it like this...

```
my_list = list(Post_Sub_Category.objects.values_list('name'), flat=True)
```

I believe my answer should also work for your edited question.

```
if 'car' in list(ddd):
```